# Editor access to plugin settings

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, dashboard, pluggable

I'm trying to give access to an user with the role Editor to this plugin settings page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/commenter-data/

In the code of this plugin on line 31 of commenter.php there is this function:

```
function cd_setting_page(){

   add_options_page( 'Commenter data Settings', 'Commenter data Settings', 'administrator', 'commenterdata-settings', array( $this, 'cd_renderer' ));
}
```

This only allows for the administrator user role to access the settings page.

I'm wondering if there is a way to override or add a filter to this function in my themes functions.php file in order for my user with the user role Editor to access this plugins settings.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I noticed if I change the 3rd parameter from administrator to edit_posts it works but if the plugin gets updated it will revert back to administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the plugin author did not leave room for a filter.  But I did request one for you [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/enhancement-3?replies=1#post-6366457).

I suggested changing:

```
/* Add option page */
function cd_setting_page(){

    add_options_page( 'Commenter data Settings', 'Commenter data Settings', 'administrator', 'commenterdata-settings', array( $this, 'cd_renderer' ));
}
```

to

```
/* Add option page */
        function cd_setting_page(){
$cap = apply_filters( 'commenter_data_settings_page_capability_filter', 'administrator' );
            add_options_page( 'Commenter data Settings', 'Commenter data Settings', $cap, 'commenterdata-settings', array( $this, 'cd_renderer' ));
        }
```

so you could use this in your theme's functions.php file if the plugin author makes it exactly what I suggested.

```
    add_filter( 'commenter_data_settings_page_capability_filter','my_settings_page_filter' );

function my_settings_page_filter( $cap )
{
// allow Editor role the ability to access Commenter Data Settings Page
return 'edit_posts';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the help!!! The plugin author told me via Twitter that he added me to the committers. I'm unsure how to make the commit but if there is a tut on how to do so I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I am author of commenter data plugin. I have addressed your concern and released version 2.1 which allows you to set the capability. Please take a look and let me know if you have any further query.